# Centering a Custom Control Programmatically on an AutoLayout View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am using this control as an Activity Indicator whenever I do a HTTP Request

https://github.com/gontovnik/DGActivityIndicatorView

Here is how I call it

```
    let activityIndicator: DGActivityIndicatorView = DGActivityIndicatorView();
    activityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height);
    activityIndicator.size = 68;
    activityIndicator.tintColor = tintColor;
    //activityIndicator.type = DGActivityIndicatorAnimationType.BallClipRotatePulse;
    activityIndicator.startAnimating();

    view.addSubview(activityIndicator);
```

I call this on `viewDidLoad` along with my HTTP Request code.

However, this will cause the activityIndicator position not at the center because in viewDidLoad the autolayout has not finished layouting yet.

I could fix this problem by placing the code on `viewDidAppear` and the activityIndicator will be positioned right.

But this is bad because the HTTP Request will only be made on viewDidAppear which is wasting one precious second.

How should I modify the control so it will center by itself?

This control is coded in Obj-C which I am not familiar with [DGActivityIndicatorView](https://github.com/gontovnik/DGActivityIndicatorView)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a way to do it within the control itself

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (self.layer.sublayers != nil) {
        self.frame = self.superview.frame;
        self.layer.position = (CGPoint){CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds)};
        self.layer.sublayers[0].position = (CGPoint){CGRectGetMidX(self.layer.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.layer.bounds)};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To put a view at the center of another view, use this line of code:

```
activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
```

Also, You can make a global property for `activityIndicator`. Then you can start the `HTTP Request` in `viewDidLoad` and write the above line in `viewDidAppear` to center the `activityIndicator`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width  / 2, 
                             view.frame.size.height / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
activityIndicator.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

let xCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: activityIndicator, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
self.view..addConstraint(xCenterConstraint)

let yCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: activityIndicator, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view., attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
self.view..addConstraint(yCenterConstraint)
```